# Write a struct with multiple variables into a single byte array

Tags: pointers, networking, types, casting, rust

I want to create a byte storage for the following structure and put both variables (`tag` and `i`/`d`) into the storage. Then I want to write the storage into the `TcpStream` in a single write; due to a bug on the server side, I can't do it with multiple calls.

I need to use a C-style API that involves unions. The total structure size is 12 bytes:

```
struct element {
    int tag;
    union {
        int i; double d;
    } data;
}
```

How do I do it? Maybe there's a better way of doing it?

Comment: *due to a bug on the server side, I can't do it with multiple calls* — just because you write it in one call doesn't mean that the server will read it in one call. That's up to how the network routes packets between the machines.

Comment: I know this. Thing is, morons who developed the server side, did actually expect whole structure to come at once. If this isn't the case, it crashes. It is good that 24 bytes is something that is expected to come in a single packet unless explicitly noted... And this is what I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should be a good start.

You need to use the [byteorder crate](https://github.com/BurntSushi/byteorder) to handle endianness and write bytes to a stream.

The `element` type can be conveniently represented as enum on the Rust side.

```
extern crate byteorder;

use std::net::TcpStream;
use byteorder::{ByteOrder, BigEndian, WriteBytesExt};
use std::io::Write;

enum Element {
    A(i32),
    B(f64)
}

impl Element {
    fn write_to_buffer<T: ByteOrder>(&self, buffer: &mut [u8; 12]) {
        let mut buffer = &mut buffer[..];
        match *self {
            Element::A(n) => {
                buffer.write_i32::<T>(0).unwrap();
                buffer.write_i32::<T>(n).unwrap();
            },
            Element::B(n) => {
                buffer.write_i32::<T>(1).unwrap();
                buffer.write_f64::<T>(n).unwrap();
            },
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:1234").unwrap();

    let mut buffer = [0u8; 12];

    let b = Element::B(317.98);

    b.write_to_buffer::<BigEndian>(&mut buffer);

    stream.write(&buffer).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: @LeontyevGeorgiy if the answer worked for you, make sure to upvote and accept it.

Comment: I can't publicly upvote it; ain't got 15 reputation yet.